# Rails Collapse Nested Errors Into Single Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm designing an API to return errors for a model that `acceptes_nested_attributes_for` a number of associations (has_many, belongs_to, etc). I'm currently looping through the errors to generate a single `error` key in the JSON response for 422 responses:

```
{ errors: @model.errors.full_messages.join(', ') }
```

However, this doesn't add detailed association errors (just 'model is invalid'). Does Rails provide an easy way to propagate the detailed errors onto the parent model?

i.e.

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_associated :parts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end

@car.errors # {:customer=>["is invalid"]} - want 'customer name must be present'
```

Comment: What is the desired JSON output?

Comment: @max I'd like the JSON response to be a single string for the `errors` key. If the part name is the only validation failing it'd be: `{ "errors": "part name must be present" }`.

Comment: Perhaps this might get you started down the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14697900/2208682